# HashiCorp Vault permission denied 403 for AppRole with assigned policy kv v2

Tags: hashicorp-vault, vault

I'm having troubles with Vault it returns permission denied 403 error, when I try to get secrets with my k8s AppRole.
I setup vault with kv version 2 engine.

[image]

Added policy for my AppRole:

[image]

Created secret under "dev/fra1/statement":
[image]

When I login with AppRole creds I have response with required policies:

[image]

When I try to execute get request with AppRole client_token I this error:

[image]

I tried different prefixes and so on (Since people on internet had problems with them).
But then was able to localize the problem, by performing that request with root token, so it went ok:
[image]

Now I'm our of ideas, I believe the only place where the problem can be is policy, what I'm doing wrong ?

Comment: HCL doesn't use * as a regex value.  Also your path doesn't match your mount (secret vs. kv)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so finally figured the right prefix our, it should be:

```
path "kv/data/dev/*" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

[image]

Really, there is some hell with these prefixes in vault, they should describe it better in docs.

Answer (score 0):

The "secret" prefix is used in v1 of Vault's KV API. v2 uses the mount name, which by default is "kv", but can be anything when you first create the mount for your KV secrets engine.

It is important to note that some tools which use Vault's API still use v1 of the KV API to access secrets, despite that your KV secrets engine may be v2. So you may need two different permissions in your policy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue. I have a secrets engine called `TestSecretsEngine` and a single secret `env`. In my policy I add read to the path `TestSecretsEngine/data/env` to no avail. I'm using the `node-vault` npm module and it's failing at `vault.approleLogin` with a 403. It's got to be something with the policy because when I add a nonexistent path, I get a 404 instead.